# PHP array element by array key

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to select an array element by its key, without having to iterate through the set `array_keys($arr)` - ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you want to select an element by it's key all you do is this:

```
<?php
echo $array_name['KEY_NAME'];
?>
```

Where "KEY_NAME" is the key you have given to that element in the array.

Comment: Apologies, it must be the value I'm testing for (albeit it seems that this just simply selects the value to which the key associates and not the value of the key itself).  E.g. I'd like to do the following...
    $arr = array("value", "a"=>"b");
    if($arr["value"]) { 
      //output something 
    } else { 
      //output something converse 
    }

Comment: Here 'value' is the actual value of the array if you wanted to access it you would do $arr[0] has you have not given it a key name like you did you b.

Comment: Thanks.  Accepting the associated value if testing the key value succeeds doesn't seem to work for some reason.  Ordinarily, I'd be required to test the value from the set returned by array_keys($arr) but would prefer an alternative that doesn't entail storing a second copy of an entire set.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for mis-presenting this problem but have found a long-lost solution now! Simply use `array_key_exists($key, $array)` to test for $key in $array.